# Application closes if any window is shown before the main window

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a very puzzling case. During the initialization of my application, before any windows are shown, this function deserializes application settings from XML file, but if deserialization function throws any errors, it displays an error message to the user (which is a custom-made WPF dialog), and once that message dialog is closed, it creates new instance of the settings, and continues the initialization:

```
Public Function LoadSettings()
    Try
        Return DeserializeFromXML(settingsPath)
    Catch ex As Exception
        Msg.ShowMessage(Msg.corruptedSettingsFile)          
        Return new AppSettings
    End Try
End Function
```

ShowMessage is defined as:

```
Public Function ShowMessage(message As Message) As Boolean
    Dim messageDialog As New MessageDialog(message.Title, message.Content, message.Buttons)
    Return messageDialog.ShowDialog()
End Function
```

Now, the weird thing is, after that exception is caught, and error message is closed by the user, initialization continues, but when it arrives at `mainWindow.Show()`, nothing happens. Main window is not shown. And once initialization code finishes, the application closes immediately.

In my Application Properties, the Shutdown mode is set to "On main window close". StartupUri is not set, because I want to show that main window exactly when I want, not automatically. However, for testing, I tried to remove `mainWindow.Show()` altogether, and set StartupUri to `MainWindow.XML`, but it doesn't solve the issue either.

I have tested that if I do not display that error message to the user, the application loads correctly, either with `mainWindow.Show()` or with StartupUri.

Why is this happening?

EDIT: I forgot to mention, which is probably important, that before the `mainWindow.Show()`, I also call `Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow`. So in case WPF makes that message dialog main window, this call should override it... But it still doesn't work.

EDIT 2: I discovered that if I call `Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown` before showing the message, and restore it with `Application.Current.ShutdownMode = ShutdownMode.OnMainWindowClose` and also call `Application.Current.MainWindow = mainWindow`, then the application does not close, and all works correctly. However, this is a horrible solution. It is obvious now that the message dialog hijacks the `Application.Current.MainWindow`. How do I stop this behavior on the application level, so that the `Application.Current.MainWindow` would only get set when I explicitly set it?

Comment: You should provide minimum, reproducible code by stripping off irrelevant codes.

Comment: @emoacht due to the findings written in my edits, that is no longer required. I figured out that the issue is caused by WPF assigning first created window as the main window of the application, so my code becomes irrelevant. All I want now is to disable this behavior, so that the main window would only be set explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

you must set `MainWindow` before calling `ShowDialog` methed of any other windows. The reason of this is: a window that was created in application thread, will set itself as main window if `MainWindow` was `null`; and after `ShowDialog` was called, you would have any chance to fix this because of modal mode.

```
// this will work.
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var a = new MainWindow();
    var b = new MessageDialog();

    b.ShowDialog();
    a.Show();
}

// this will not.
private void Application_Startup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var b = new MessageDialog();
    b.ShowDialog(); //app shutdown at this point

    var a = new MainWindow();
    a.Show();
}
```

Comment: I understand this, but the problem is, I need to make these checks during the creation of the Model and ViewModel for that main window that I intend to show; therefore I cannot create it earlier than that message dialog might be shown, as it's binding will have nothing to bind to. Instead, I want to disable that behavior that you described (assigning the first window shown as the main window of the application).

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas there's no way to disable it, since it's part of `Window`'s construction code.  but you can walk around this. simply way is create a blank window instance first but not show it, after your `MessageDialog` closed, set `MainWindow` to your real one. or you can create your `MessageDialog` in another thread, then use a `WaitHandle` to insure remaining code only be executed after `MessageDialog` was closed.

Comment: @JustinasRubinovas or you can also set `ShutdownMode` to `ShutdownMode.OnExplicitShutdown`, then call `Application.Shutdown` on `MainWindow.Closed` event.